# Интерполяция строк в C# 6 без использования $

Tags: c#, строки, интерполяция

В конфигурационном JSON файле используются строки следующего вида:

```
{
  "logFilePattern" : "{yyyy}.{mm}.{dd}.log"
}
```

Для замены используется множество разных текстовых заполнителей: вычисляемые пути файловой системы, которые зависят от пользователя и т.д.. Предполагается их замена и для этого в предыдущих версиях C# использовалось составное форматирование (могу ошибаться в термине) таким образом:

```
string name = "Fred";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name = {0}", name));
// output: "Name = Fred"
```

С выходом C# 6 версии появилась возможность использовать именованные аргументы (могу ошибаться в термине) таким образом:

```
string name = "Fred";
Console.WriteLine($"Name = {name}");
// output: "Name = Fred"
```

Вопрос: как интерполировать строку с именованными аргументами сохраненую в переменной?

```
string stringPattern = "Name = {name}";
string name = "Fred";
// ?
```

---

Нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360534/3129992) что это не возможно, т.к. код:

```
string name = "Fred";
string name2 = $"Name = {name}";
```

, компилятором приводится к:

```
string name = "fred";
string name2 = String.Format("Name = {0}", name);
```

Другим словами, это просто синтаксический сахар.

Comment: Вот тут есть ещё куча способов решения аналогичной задачи: [Есть ли аналог preg_replace в c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846489/178779)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**

Если весь вопрос в том, как сгенерировать имя лог файла, то может проще обойтись таким способом? В конфигурации задаем валидный с т.з. .NET формат для даты:

```
{
  "logFilePattern" : "yyyy.MM.dd.log"
}
```

Затем в коде выкусываем его и получаем имя файла:

```
const string extension = ".log";
var datePattern = logFilePattern.Remove(logFilePattern.IndexOf(extension), extension.Length);
DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var logFileName = date.ToString(datePattern) + extension;
```

---

**О задаче в общем**

Наивная реализация может состоять просто в замене значения:

```
string stringPattern = "Name = {name}";
string name = "Fred";
string formatted = stringPattern.Replace($"{{nameof(name)}}", name);
```

Тут есть два недостатка:

- код неуниверсальный (хотелось бы иметь отдельный метод, типа `FormatString(pattern, value1, value2, ...)`)
- не учитывается возможное эскапирование фигурных скобок (строка `"{{name}}"` не является шаблоном, однако замена будет произведена)
- при наличии нескольких значений мы будем плодить лишние строки

Метод вида `FormatString(pattern, value1, value2, ...)`, насколько я понимаю, нереален, поскольку нет способа в вызываемом методе узнать имена параметров, с которыми он вызывался. Поэтому можно остановиться на, например, словаре:

```
public static string FormatString(string pattern, IDictionary<string, object> values)
```

Эскапирование можно обработать регулярным выражением, но учитывая, что параметров может быть несколько, это тоже может быть излишне тяжелой операцией. Поэтому реализация в общем-то зависит от желаемой степени оптимизированности, в идеале надо вручную проходить `char[]`/`List<char>` и менять его на ходу.

На ночь глядя получилось так:

```
public static string FormatString(string pattern, IDictionary<string, object> values)
{
    var buffer = pattern.ToList();
    int replaceStartIndex = -1;
    int replaceEndIndex = -1;

    int index = 0;
    while (index < buffer.Count)
    {
        var character = buffer[index];
        if (character == '{')
        {
            if (replaceStartIndex == -1)
            {
                replaceStartIndex = index;
            }
            else
            {
                replaceStartIndex = -1;
            }
        }
        else if (character == '}')
        {
            if (replaceEndIndex == -1)
            {
                replaceEndIndex = index;
            }
            else
            {
                replaceEndIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        if (replaceStartIndex > -1 && replaceEndIndex > -1)
        {
            var key = new string(buffer.Skip(replaceStartIndex + 1).Take(replaceEndIndex - replaceStartIndex - 1).ToArray());
            var value = values[key];
            var stringValue = value?.ToString();
            buffer.RemoveRange(replaceStartIndex, replaceEndIndex - replaceStartIndex + 1);
            if (stringValue != null)
            {
                buffer.InsertRange(replaceStartIndex, stringValue.ToCharArray());
                index = replaceStartIndex + stringValue.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                index = replaceStartIndex;
            }
            replaceStartIndex = -1;
            replaceEndIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }
    }

    return string.Join("", buffer);
}
```

Проверка:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string stringPattern = "Name = {name}, Age = {age}, Null = {nullString}, Escape = {{escape}}";
    string name = "Fred";
    int age = 42;
    string nullString = null;
    string escape = "You shouldn't see this";
    var values = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        [nameof(name)] = name,
        [nameof(age)] = age,
        [nameof(nullString)] = nullString,
        [nameof(escape)] = escape
    };
    string formatted = FormatString(stringPattern, values);
    Console.WriteLine(formatted);
}
```

Вывод:

> Name = Fred, Age = 42, Null = , Escape = {{escape}}

Comment: В сети не мало примеров (например: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables ), но нужно получить именно такое-же поведение, как и у оригинала.

Comment: @XelaNimed а чем вас не устраивает пример по ссылке? Результат ведь тот же выдается. Что вы имеете в виду под "таким же поведением"?

Comment: В приведенном примере необходимо передавать объект, содержащий данные для замены. При использовании же стандартного способа, строки интерполируются переменными из текущей области видимости.

Comment: @XelaNimed ну так в приведенном вами примере несложно заменить `source` на словарь, получится вызов примерно с такой же сигнатурой как у меня и с переменными из текущей области видимости. Добавьте что ли в вопросе псевдокод, как вы себе это представляете.

Comment: я c# только учить начал, но мне кажется должна быть возможность реализовать это без костылей. Знак @ можно же использовать с переменной, скорее всего и здесь можно каким-либо образом. В противном случае, конечно придется через словарь прогонять.

Comment: @XelaNimed нет, такой возможности, к сожалению, нет. Посмотрите мое обновление вверху ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) сказано, что приведенная в топике строка является типом `System.FormattableString`.
По поводу которого [читаем](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring.aspx) что можно получить по индексу нужный инжектированный параметр. И просто можем сформировать новую строку со своим инжектом.
Это возможно в рамках передаваемой интерполированной строки в функцию, например..
Возможно таким способом получить нужный результат?!

Comment: не уверен, что правильно понял, но мне кажется, что Вы не уловили суть моего вопроса. Во-первых, приведенная строка не `System.FormattableString`, а `System.String`.  Проблема и заключается в том, чтоб привести обычную строку, находящуюся в переменной, к `System.FormattableString`.

Comment: Можешь добавить пример кода, чтобы было понятно, как может помочь FormattableString в данном случае?

Comment: @Grundy в FormattableString можно было бы использовать метод https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.getarguments?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_FormattableString_GetArguments

Comment: @XelaNimed, понятно :)