# Шаблон строки, который может изменять пользователь

Tags: c#

У нас в c# есть возможность формировать строку по шаблону: `string s = string.Format("Это текст: {0}", txt);` или в новой версии `string s = $"Это текст: {txt}"`

А как сделать возможным составлять пользователю подобный шаблон, и потом его использовать в уже в коде?

К примеру:

```
string Name = "Максим";
string Age = "31";
string Street = "Красная";
```

Пользователь в `Textbox` задает шаблон вывода: `"{Имя} живет на улице {Улица}"`
В результате должно получиться : `"Максим живет на улице Красная"`
Т.е. вместо {Имя} я подставляю Name, вместо {Улица} - Street.

Comment: только через `Replace` самому разбирать что ввел пользователь и подставлять

Comment: наверное делать своего рода словарь

Comment: @Grundy вы уверены? Я в курсовой подобным пользовался. Старой версией

Comment: @pavel, возможно я просто не понял, что именно будет вводить пользователь и как это потом будет использоваться

Comment: @MaximK, добавь пример, что может ввести пользователь и как это потом должно использоваться

Comment: Возможно поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564003/ Если поможет, скажите, закроем этот вопрос как дубликат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал вот так.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputString = "{Name}. Возраст {Age}. Живет по адресу {Adress}";

        TestClass test = new TestClass() {
                              Name="Max",
                              Adress="Krymsk",
                              Age=31};

        Dictionary<string, Object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("{Name}", test.Name);
        dict.Add("{Age}", test.Age);
        dict.Add("{Adress}", test.Adress);           

       Console.WriteLine(FormattedString(inputString, dict));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static string FormattedString(string pattern, Dictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        string resultStr = pattern;

        foreach (var keyVal in values)
        {
           int idx = resultStr.IndexOf(keyVal.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if ( idx > -1)
            {
                string tmp = resultStr.Substring(idx, keyVal.Key.Length);                    
                resultStr = resultStr.Replace(tmp, keyVal.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        return resultStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый параметр функции `string.Format` это обычная строка. Не важно откуда она будет браться: из переменной, либо из литерала строки.

Важно только, чтобы количество параметров используемое в шаблоне было не больше, чем количество параметров переданных в функцию `string.Format`.

Поэтому вполне возможно позволить вводить пользователю шаблон, который будет потом использовать в этой функции, проблема будет только в проверке того, сколько параметров использует пользователь в своем шаблоне, и передачи соответствующих параметров в коде при вызове.

В случае с интерполяцией строк - использовать невозможно, так как эта запись преобразуется во время компиляции в тот же вызов `string.Format`.