# Шаблон с помощью интерполяции строк

Tags: c#

Имеется строка шаблон:

```
pattern = "{Par1}, {Par2}";
```

эту переменную я получаю в одном из методов, в котором определяются переменные Name и Age.

```
public string getParams(string pattern) {
    var Par1 = "test";
    var Par2 = "44";

    return ...
}
```

Как мне вернуть интерполированную строку?

Comment: И еще один связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583379/186999

Comment: Придется через `string.Format`, тогда вам нужно писать не `{Par1}, {Par2}` а `{0}, {1}`.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, но думал будет проще, а так все выглядит как костыль)

Comment: @Odyssey, просто суть интерполяции именно в том, что она во время компиляции в string.format перегоняется.