# Есть ли аналог preg_replace в c#?

Tags: c#, шаблонизаторы

Есть массив "шаблонных слов". Можно ли прочитав шаблон(pattern) с БД сделать автозамену "шаблонных слов" на нужные.  Например

> "Здраствуйте %client%. Ваш заказ %order% будет доставлен %date%".

Ну если есть массив `Dictionary<string,string>` например, или если два массива - что заменять, и на что заменять. Т.е. встроеный шаблонизатор.

Или... хотя бы... делать это через Regex или есть более короткое рашение.

Comment: Есть ли у RegEx в с# автозамена по номеру найденого шаблона? Типа $1 $2 $3? Как это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141069/what-is-1-and-2-in-regular-expressions Применим ли такой метод тут?

Comment: а чем просто string.replace не нравится?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, точно...  А так что б не обворачивать в foreach ничего нету?

Comment: linq aggrerate? тот же foreach, только мозг выносит )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, что никто в итоге не предложил вариант на регекспах, он, вроде, не сложен:

```
var template = "Здравствуйте, %client%! Ваш заказ %order% будет доставлен %date%.";
var pattern = "%.*?%";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["%client%"] = "Иван Иванович",
    ["%order%"] = "№007",
    ["%date%"] = "сегодня"
};
string evaluator(Match match) => dict.TryGetValue(match.Value, out var replacement) ? replacement : "n/a";
var result = Regex.Replace(template, pattern, evaluator);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Если не хотите держать в словаре все эти `%`, можно искать не `match.Value`, а `match.Value.Trim('%')`

Comment: Я бился бился над regex но... и выражение неверно записал, и evaluator тоже. А с лямбдой вообще в одну строчку. Когда нету обьектов, то regex пожалуй - хороший вариант.

Comment: Ну тут небольшой нюанс в том, что требуется ленивое выражение (квантификатор `?`), иначе он захватит всё от первого вхождения `%` до последнего.

Comment: Интересно какой из ответов самый быстрый.... Возможно будет время, попробую все. Почему то думаю что regex выиграет)

Comment: Хорошо. Добавлю http://www.exlab.net/files/tools/sheets/regexp/regexp.png

Comment: @nick_n_a и почему же вы так думаете?

Comment: @nick_n_a я думаю, что медленней регулярок будет только рефлексия

Comment: @tym32167, что интересно, регулярка медленнее рефлексии (!), и только скомпилированный вариант регулярки догоняет ее: https://pastebin.com/RX9U1Nfv Сами тесты: https://pastebin.com/1raqiekJ

Comment: @АндрейNOP ничего удивительного, регулярки - штуки медленные, особенно не скомпилированные.

Comment: @tym32167, рефлексия тоже медленная, просто интересно узнать кто из них медленней

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну это от алгоритма ж зависит. Если компилируете регулярки, то и кешируйте их, как и кешируйте полученные свойства с типа в рефлексии, чтобы было честно )))

Answer (score 4):

Простой пример

```
var pattern = "%1% - %2% - %3%";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"%1%","odin"}, {"%2%","dwa"}, {"%3%","tri"}};

var res = dict.Aggregate(pattern, (acc, p)=>acc.Replace(p.Key, p.Value));

Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Вывод

```
odin - dwa - tri
```

Comment: Согласен. Без лямды будет foreach. Наверно встроеной нету.

Comment: @nick_n_a я как то писал шаблонизатор простенький, года 3 назад, так как стандартного не нашел. Но, в итоге, оно все равно в какой то цикл скатывается с заменой. Так что я бы расслабился и пользовал что нравится :) Да и что встроенное вам надо? тут и так 1 строчка кода по сути

Answer (score 3):

Раз пошла такая пьянка, добавлю немного мракобесия

```
public string Format<T>(string source, T data)
{
    var res = source;
    foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        res = res.Replace($"%{p.Name}%", p.GetValue(data)?.ToString()); 
    return res;
}

var pattern = "%name% - %date% - %age%";
Console.WriteLine(Format(pattern, new {name = "vasya", date = DateTime.Now, age = 18}));
```

Вывод

```
vasya - 25-Jun-18 16:06:20 - 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - `string.Format`:

```
var template = "Здравствуйте {0}. Ваш заказ {1} будет доставлен {2:dd.MM.yyyy}";
string.Format(template, "Вася", "фиговина", DateTime.Today);
```

При желании несложно сделать и выбор параметров по именам:

```
var template = "Здравствуйте {0:client}. Ваш заказ {0:order} будет доставлен {0:date:dd.MM.yyyy}";
string.Format(template, new CompositeFormattable(new
{
    client = "Вася",
    order = "фиговина",
    date = DateTime.Today,
}));

// ...

class CompositeFormattable : IFormattable
{
    private readonly object obj;
    public CompositeFormattable(object obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        var index = format.IndexOf(':');
        string propname;
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            propname = format.Substring(0, index);
            format = format.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            propname = format;
            format = null;
        }

        var value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propname).GetValue(obj);
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var formattableValue = value as IFormattable;
        if (formattableValue != null)
            return formattableValue.ToString(format, provider);
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Вариант через регулярки также возможен (метод Regex.Replace).

Answer (score -2):

У меня получилось так, хотя, может быть, не самым оптимальным образом

```
string textInput = "Здраствуйте %client%. Ваш заказ %order% будет доставлен %date%";
Dictionary<string, string> masks = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "%client%", "Иванов" },
    { "%order%", "Заказ №123" },
    { "%date%", "2 апреля 23:05" },
};

var query = (from s in textInput.Split(' ')
             from m in masks
             select s.Replace(m.Key, m.Value) into r
             where !r.StartsWith("%")
             select r).Distinct();


string result = String.Join(" ", query);
```

Comment: зачем столько ограничений? Тут и пробелы нельзя юзать внутри идентификатора, и замену на % нельзя, и одинаковые слова убирает - как то много ограничений

Comment: @tym32167 у меня с LINQ, честно сказать, некоторые трудности имеются:) Вот про `Aggregate()` я даже и не вспомнил, а зря. У вас хорошо получилось.

Comment: Есть такая книжка [Pro linq](https://www.apress.com/gb/book/9781430226536) - я её лет 8 назад прочитал бегом и вроде с тех пор все на места встало :) Гораздо проще стало с linq работать, хотя к sql-синтаксису так и не привык

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, почитаю.