# C#. Вставить значение при помощи регулярного выражения в строку вида {AddressDevice:X2}

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

есть строка где между {} задается место для вставки переменной.
Для цифровых переменных можно указать формат вставки `{AddressDevice:X2}`
значит переменная `AddressDevice = 5`, вставка будет в hex формате `05`.

для примера есть строка:

```
 "STX{AddressDevice:X2}{Nbyte:X2}"
```

В ней нужно заменить только {AddressDevice:X2}.
Я сделал реализацию где делаю split строк по } и разбираю потом по отдельности, это как то не оптимально. Подскажите можно ли это сделать с помощью

```
  Regex.Replace(...)
```

Те если AddressDevice = 5, после вставки должно быть 
 "STX05{Nbyte:X2}"

Comment: Ничего не понятно. откуда берутся переменные, почему вторые скобки не заменяются...

Comment: В этом обработчике нужно заменить только 1 переменную {AddressDevice:X2}. вторую не трогаем, там строка очень большая переменных и просто констант много, нужно заменить только AddressDevice. Какая разница откуда переменная для подстановки? int AddressDevice = 5;

Comment: У вас есть также набор наименований переменных, которые надо заменить? Очень похожая задача: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846489/218063

Comment: Да все верно но решил я ее не оптимально как мне кажется, поэтому я выделил подзадачу из большой задачи,просто на замену одной переменной по формату. Этот алгоритм разбился на конвеер обработки строки, раньше все решалось в одном цикле который пробегал по подстрокам.

Comment: Если просто заменять {AddressDevice} то я могу написать регулярку, но заменить по формату {AddressDevice:X2 не прибегая к циклу не выходит

Comment: Не вижу никаких проблем, посмотрите мой ответ в указанном топике. Вам по сути надо переписать регулярку, так чтобы она захватывала 2 группы и переписать функцию `evaluator`, так, чтобы она по первой группе захвата искала значение, а по второй брала аргумент для `ToString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение является адаптацией [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849494/218063):

```
var template = "Здравствуйте, {client}! Ваш заказ №{order:X2} будет доставлен {date:d}.";
var pattern = @"\{(.*?)(:.+?)?\}";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["client"] = "Иван Иванович",
    ["order"] = 5,
    ["date"] = DateTime.Today
};
string evaluator(Match match)
{
    var replacement = dict[match.Groups[1].Value];
    var format = "{0" + match.Groups[2].Value + "}";
    return string.Format(format, replacement);
}
var result = Regex.Replace(template, pattern, evaluator);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вывод:

```
Здравствуйте, Иван Иванович! Ваш заказ №05 будет доставлен 12.11.2018.
```

Регулярное выражение ищет совпадение и выделяет в нем две группы (по числу пар круглых скобок), к которым мы потом обращаемся по индексу (1 и 2, т.к. нулевая группа — это всё выражение полностью).

`.*?` — любое количество (`*`) любых символов (`.`), поиск ленивый (`?`), т. е. захватывает минимальное количество символов, которые соответствуют шаблону (если группу оставить жадной, как по умолчанию, то она за один раз захватит всё что между первой открывающей и последней закрывающей фигурными скобками.

`:.+?` — двоеточие (`:`) потом за ним один или более (`+`) любых символов (`.`), поиск ленивый (`?`).

`(...)?` — группа необязательная, при отсутствии получим просто пустую строку.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас адаптирую

Comment: а можете точнее расписать var pattern = @"\{(.*?)(:.+?)?\}";   что делает (.*?)   и этот (:.+?)?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.