# C#: "$\"{Count} Details\"" to string interpolation in code

Tags: c#, json

есть json Запись "$"{Count} Details"", которая при десериализации записывается в string переменную. Можно ли потом использовать символ $ для вставки нужного мне значения переменной. Пока что чет ничего не работает.

```
int Count = 4;
string description = "$\"{Count} Details\""
```

;

Comment: Нет. Это работает на этапе компиляции кода.

Comment: `string description = string.Format("{0} Details", Count);` то есть в строке шаблон форматирования, а значение подставляется а него потом.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564003/182750)

Comment: Спасибо) Да я могу использовать Формат. Но Тут мысль именно в именном параметре ка. Лад спаисбо) попробуем придумать чтото)

Comment: @XelaNimed да почти то что нужно. в целом хотел попробовать екранировать запись в джейсоне чтоб потом распарсить) и привести к нужному мне виду